# Enable PS ExecutionPolicy from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

i would like to setup powershell execution to unrestricted from script itself.

I have working version in console app. It looks something like this:

```
public static void SetPowerShellExecuteUnrestricted()
    {
        try
        {
            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke();
            scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But now i need the same in WPF application. The code above wont work.
So i tried different versions for example:
Through RunspaceFactory:

```
Runspace rs;
            rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            rs.Open();

            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
                ps.Runspace = rs;
                ps.Invoke();
            }
```

This will catch Exception: "Set-ExecutionPolicy" is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. But this cmdlet normally works in powershell console.

I even tried to do it from windows cmd like this:

```
string strCmdText = "/C PowerShell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted";
            Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

But this way cmd window do one flash then disseaper but executionpolicy is not changed.

Was anyone dealing with similar problem and could help?

Thanks

//EDIT 25.08.2019 21:10
Tried one more thing but no succes:

```
void CreateScript()
            {
                string path = @"C:\Windows\Temp\ExecPolicy.ps1";
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
                    }
                }

            }

            void RunPowershellScript(string PathToScript)
            {
                string strCmdText;
                strCmdText = PathToScript;
                Process.Start("C:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe ", strCmdText);
            }

            CreateScript();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            RunPowershellScript(@"C:\Windows\Temp\ExecPolicy.ps1");
```

Creating file with script and then run it with powershell. But no succes. You cant run it cause its disabled by that ExecutionPolicy....

//EDIT 25.08.2019 21:55

Ok guys i figure it out.

Here is solution:
You need to formulate command like this:

```
ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("Unrestricted").AddParameter("Scope", "CurrentUser");
```

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. So that others can find it more easily, please post it as an _answer_, ideally with an explanation. After 48 hours you'll be able to accept your own answer, to guide future readers.